# Excel VBA: On Close Save Prompt after ActiveX Resize Despite Thisworkbook.Saved=True

Tags: excel, vba, activex

I've run into an interesting situation with Excel, and I was wondering if anyone of you knew an answer / solution.

Setup:
I have an empty excel worksheet with a ActiveX ToggleButton on it.
In a VBA code, I change the width of the button to 0, and then change the width to 100. (Why I do that is a different question, its part of a larger project, however, this causes the problem).

Then I set the save-status of the workbook to true, without actually saving the workbook.

Normally, if I now closed the workbook, it would just close, without asking me wether I want to save. 
Now, due to the resizing, and even though the .Saved-Status is True, it asks me if I want to save when I close the workbook, and by clicking onto the close Icon of excel, the .Saved-Status is set to "False"

If you want to try for yourself, try the below steps.
Alternatively, I uploaded for convenience the same file here: (https://filebin.ca/3aLbbRxMTdUs/SavePromptUponResize.xlsm)

1) create a new workbook and add a new ACTIVEX toggle button.
2) in the VBA code of the workbook, add the below code
3) save the workbook, close it, and reopen it. 
4) You should see a messagebox and after clicking, as second one
5) Now the status of the workbook is "saved"
6) Try to close the workbook -> you will be prompted if you want to save
7) If you check the .saved status now, it would say "false"

Looking forward to your insights!

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
MsgBox "Now a macro will run and resize twice the button you see." & vbCrLf & "Afterwards, the status of the workbook will be set to 'saved'." & vbCrLf & "However, upon closing, excel will still prompt to save."
Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Sheets(1)


ws.Shapes("ToggleButton1").Width = 0
ws.Shapes("ToggleButton1").Width = 100


wb.Saved = True
MsgBox "Macro finished, save status is: " & wb.Saved


End Sub



Private Sub CheckSaveStatus()
MsgBox "Save status is: " & ActiveWorkbook.Saved
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try the below:

```
Option Explicit

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer


Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)

If i = 1 Then

wb.Saved = False

Else

wb.Saved = True


End If

End Sub    


Private Sub Workbook_Open()


MsgBox "Now a macro will run and resize twice the button you see." & vbCrLf & "Afterwards, the status of the workbook will be set to 'saved'." & vbCrLf & "However, upon closing, excel will still prompt to save."

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Sheets(1)


ws.Shapes("ToggleButton1").Width = 0
ws.Shapes("ToggleButton1").Width = 100

End Sub


Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
i = 1
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, Nikolaos,
In your suggestion, you set the "saved" flag upon closing the workbook. This will indeed prevent the "save-prompt" from appearing.
However, it will in all cases cause the "save prompt" to be omitted, even in occasions where after opening the workbook and running the "Workbook_Open" routine the user makes changes to the workbook. In these cases, the save dialog should not be omitted.

Therefore, I think the "wb.Saved = True" flag needs to be set in the "Workbook_Open" routine, and a way needs to be found how it remains "true" when closing, if no additional changes happen.

Comment: Please check my answer again, I think that is ok now.

Comment: I am not sure what the solution you did does now - the Workbook_BeforeSave part prevents any saving.

It is not that I want to prevent saving. If the user decides to make changs to the workbook (e.g., write some text into a cell), then the Save prompt should rightfully come up. However, if the user only opens the workbook, the macro resizes the button, and then the user directly closes, then no save prompt should come up.

Comment: i think you didn't read from the beginning my solution...please do the below: Disable all Macros, write the code from my answer and save. After opening your file enable Macros Save and Close. Open the file and you will have the desired results, no one can save in this sheet.

Comment: please check my new answer..i think that is ok now

Answer (score 1):

The solution is as simple as this:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
  MsgBox "Now a macro will run and resize twice the button you see." & vbCrLf & "Afterwards, the status of the workbook will be set to 'saved'." & vbCrLf & "However, upon closing, excel will still prompt to save."
  Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
  Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Sheets(1)
  Dim boolSaved As Boolean

  boolSaved = wb.Saved
  ws.Shapes("ToggleButton1").Width = 0
  ws.Shapes("ToggleButton1").Width = 100
  If boolSaved Then wb.Save

  MsgBox "Macro finished, save status is: " & wb.Saved

End Sub
```

This technique can be used anywhere in your code where you need to do something that 'dirties' the workbook. The beauty of it is that it preserves the save prompt if the user *has* modified the workbook.

As to why it's happening, best guess is - a(nother) ActiveX bug in Excel.

Comment: Hi robinCTS, thanks for your suggestion!
Unfortunately, that is a "shortcut" which does not work in my scenario. Essentially what you do is you actually perfrom a save, whilst I only "fake" a save. 
In my scenario, this shortcut is not possible, and inside the "Workbook_Open" routine, no actual saving should occur, and at the end of the "Workbook_Open" the state of the workbook should be "Saved = True", regardless of the actions performed within the routine. If the user then does no further changes, closing should not cause a save prompt

Comment: @Benjamin Added some extra info for you.

Comment: The line : If boolSaved Then wb.Save, 

make the excel to cancel the prompt to save because has already save.

its a good trick!!Nice Code!!

Comment: You yould simply even say "wb.Save", without the "boolSaved". You essentially save the excel; but the core of the problem is not solved: that he "fake" saved status (its not saved, but excel think its saved) is not respected when closing. In the proposed solution, the saved status is not "fake", but is in fact saved...

Comment: @Benjamin Yeah. I was just showing the general solution for your larger project, which respects the user's saved state. For the example you posted you only need the `wb.Save`. When the normal hammer won't do the trick, time to get out the *sledge* hammer ;)

Comment: fair enough, robin ;)

Comment: @Benjamin I somehow completely missed your first comment. Can you explain exactly *why* no actual saving should occur inside the `Workbook_Open` handler?

Comment: @robinCTS Sure. In the scenario where the workbook is used, not all of the people reading it have write access. There are some users that only need to read the excel for information, and then they close it without any changes. They will never do changes, and thus should not get a "save prompt". Others have write access and do changes, thus is if they actually do changes (beyond the ones done automatically by Workbok_Open handler) then this should trigger a save prompt. I'm aware its a very particular scenario, still I was hoping to find a solution that works in all scenarios

Answer (score 0):

My experience has been that this Excel bug is triggered as a result of using VBA code to change the value of some properties of some ActiveX/OLE controls.  I don't have a complete list of such properties but here's a few:

CommandButton:

- **Enabled** property
- **Height** property

TextBox:

- **ForeColor** property
- **BackColor** property

I use a generalized system (similar to Nikolaos Polygenis's solution), including extensive explanation due to this bug's subtlety, as follows:

1. In a standard module, define a project-global variable to indicate the no-save-needed condition:
   `'*************************************************************************************************************
   'EXCEL OLE/ACTIVE-X SAVE-BUG WORKAROUND - BUG WORKAROUND - BUG WORKAROUND - BUG WORKAROUND - BUG WORKAROUND
   '
   '(See the Workbook_BeforeClose event handler, in the ThisWorkbook module, for a complete explanation.)
   '
   Public SuppressWkBkSaveMsg As Boolean
   '
   'END SAVE-BUG WORKAROUND - END WORKAROUND - END WORKAROUND - END WORKAROUND - END WORKAROUND - END WORKAROUND
   '*************************************************************************************************************`
2. In the ThisWorkbook module, place the following Workbook_BeforeClose event handler, with full explanation:

   `Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
   '*************************************************************************************************************
   'EXCEL OLE/ACTIVE-X SAVE-BUG WORKAROUND - BUG WORKAROUND - BUG WORKAROUND - BUG WORKAROUND - BUG WORKAROUND
   '
   'Excel has a very subtle bug in which, if you change the value of some properties of some ActiveX/OLE
   'controls, the parent workbook's Saved property will not function correctly until the next actual workbook
   'save event.  That is, you can subsequently set the workbook's Saved property to True but Excel will still
   'prompt the user about whether to save the workbook when closing it.  In fact, if you check the value of the
   'Saved property in a Workbook_BeforeClose event handler, it will be defined as False even though no changes
   'have been made to the workbook after explicitly setting it to True!
   '
   'The most effective workaround is to defer the override of the workbook's Saved property until the Close event
   'has been actually initiated: declare the project-global SuppressWkBkSaveMsg variable in a standard module,
   'add this Workbook_BeforeClose event handler to the ThisWorkbook module, and then set SuppressWkBkSaveMsg to
   'True whenever it's necessary to suppress Excel's user-inquiry about whether to save changes to the workbook
   'before closing it.
   '
   If SuppressWkBkSaveMsg Then Me.Saved = True
   '
   'END SAVE-BUG WORKAROUND - END WORKAROUND - END WORKAROUND - END WORKAROUND - END WORKAROUND - END WORKAROUND
   '*************************************************************************************************************
   End Sub`
3. In any location in the code, in any module, whenever it's necessary to suppress Excel's user-inquiry about whether to save changes to the workbook before closing it, set SuppressWkBkSaveMsg to True:

   `'Do stuff that doesn't need to be saved, including modifications to OLE/ActiveX control-objects...
   '
   '*************************************************************************************************************
   'EXCEL OLE/ACTIVE-X SAVE-BUG WORKAROUND - BUG WORKAROUND - BUG WORKAROUND - BUG WORKAROUND - BUG WORKAROUND
   '
   '(See the Workbook_BeforeClose event handler, in the ThisWorkbook module, for a complete explanation.)
   '
   SuppressWkBkSaveMsg = True
   '
   'END SAVE-BUG WORKAROUND - END WORKAROUND - END WORKAROUND - END WORKAROUND - END WORKAROUND - END WORKAROUND
   '*************************************************************************************************************
   '
   '...`